# Get error when trying to .update() a model on sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

As you'll see in the code below I'm able to find the user because I get the console.log('log1', userSettings.PASSWORD); printed in the terminal, and I get a user.Settings.PASSWORD returned. So up to this point everything works fine. 
But when I attempt to do the update I end up getting the error:

I get the following error: Details:  RequestError: Invalid column name 'id'

This is how my code looks like:

```
  updateSettings: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      sails.models.customer.findOne()
        .where({
          USERNAME: params.username,
          PASSWORD: params.currentPassword
        }).exec(function(err, userSettings) {
          if (err) {
            reject(new Error('Error finding user'));
            console.error(err);
          }else if (userSettings) {
            console.log('log1', userSettings.PASSWORD);
            sails.models.customer.update({
              USERNAME: params.username
            },
            {
              PASSWORD: params.newPassword
            }).exec(function(err, userSettingsUpdated) {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(new Error('Error updating the user settings'));
              }else {
                fullfill(userSettingsUpdated);

              }
            });
          }

        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I feel your problem doesn't lie in this part of the code. Can you also attach the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails.js / Waterline [already implements Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline) as the promise library, so you can use the query methods as promises (depending on the version you use, of course).

I took the liberty to rewrite your code. I transformed `sails.models.customer` into `Customer`. Excuse this please if there is a reason you are using `sails.models.customer`.

As galactocalypse already stated, the error may not be in the code you posted though. I assume the error might occur because you don't have an ID attribute in your `Customer` model that sails wants to use to save your `Customer` instance.

Just post back if you need more help.

```
updateSettings: function(params) {

    var where = {
        USERNAME: params.username,
        PASSWORD: params.currentPassword
    };

    return Customer.findOne().where(where)
        .then(function(userSettings) {
            sails.log.info('log1', userSettings.PASSWORD);
            return Customer.update({ USERNAME: params.username }, {PASSWORD: params.newPassword});
        })
        .then(function(userSettingsUpdated) { /* do whatever you want here */ })
        .catch(function(err) { sails.log.error(err); });
});
```